# php using header to Redirect

Tags: php

I am new to php. I have Form on a page with a button that once clicked it pops up another sub page :

```
onclick="newPopup('page2.php','750','500')
```

**page2.php** has another button, I want to be able to redirect the Main Page to another url using this pop-up.

How can I do this?

Comment: if `page2.php` is a popup window. Just close the window on click event to get back to previous page.

Comment: I want to redirect the previous page on that closing event but i'am new i m stuck at it i don't know how to manage it working

Comment: If you want to redirect the main page on a button click in the popup, you need to do this with JS, not PHP. On the second button, try: `onclick="window.opener.location='someurl.php';"`.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson Must be an answer! , thank you so much !

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect the main page on a button click in the popup, you need to do this with JS, not PHP.

Add this to the button in the popup:

```
onclick="window.opener.location.href='someurl.php'";
```

From a popup, you can access the page/window that opened the popup with: `window.opener`. This means that you also can call functions on the main page: `window.opener.someFunctionOnTheMainPage()`.

Answer (score 0):

On click of button, you can execute below JavaScript:

```
window.opener.location.href = 'new URL';
```

This will redirect your parent page to the new URL.